# Access Compare each row to each other

Tags: sql, ms-access

A couple tables are being combined to have a plan number, activity number, date/time workdate, resource number and $ Rate in one table. I am trying to only return records where the Rate is above $15.00 **for every record in that planno** (rate is determined by resno number) for each planno.

So,

```
P000 R100 $10.00
P000 R100 $10.00
P000 R101 $20.00
```

would not return anything.
However,

```
P102 R102 $15.00
P102 R103 $17.50
P102 R03  $17.50
```

would return all three of those rows. 
Here is my code. This obviously an nested query, maybe a self join. However, I just can't seem to get it. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT EventPlan.planno
    ,EventPlan.activity
    ,EventPlan.workdate
    ,EventPlanLine.resno
    ,Resource.Rate
FROM EventPlan
INNER JOIN (
    Resource INNER JOIN EventPlanLine ON Resource.resno = EventPlanLine.resno
    ) ON (EventPlan.planno = EventPlanLine.planno)
WHERE (
        ((Month([EventPlan].[workdate])) = 12)
        AND ((Year([EventPlan].[workdate])) = 2013)
        );
```

EventPlan

```
planno  eventno workdate        activity                    empno
P100    E100    25-Oct-13       Operation                   E102
P101    E104    03-Dec-13       Operation                   E100
P102    E105    05-Dec-13       Operation                   E102
```

Resource

```
resno   resname      rate
R100    attendant   $10.00
R101    police      $15.00
R102    usher       $10.00
R104    janitor     $15.00
```

EventPlanLine

```
planno  lineno  timestart   timeend number  locno       resno
P104      2      18:00       22:00  4       L100        R104
P104      1      18:00       22:00  4       L101        R104
P105      2      18:00       22:00  4       L100        R104
P105      1      18:00       22:00  4       L101        R104
```

I believe in the rows I have provided, all four lines in the EventPlanLine should be returned, as both **plannos have all their rates** above $15.00

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve] of your problem. You've already got 3 tables in your join, and your sample doesn't reflect what's in what and what the exact nature of your problem is.

Comment: i dont see any comparing the values in where  clause for the rate. check your where clause again.

Comment: And `P000 R101 $20.00` is above $10. So why to exclude?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. First time using SO for SQL. Thanks. I think the rate comparison goes in the nested loop in the FROM clause